# How to set Keyboard Shortcut for moving windows across Monitor in GNOME?

Tags: gnome

I use GNOME 3 DE on ubuntu 14.04 . In unity, I set keyboard shorcut on ccsm so that I could move windows from monitor 1 to monitor 2 with keyboard shortcut. But when i switched to GNOME, ccsm doesnt work anymore. How do I suppose to do it in GNOME?

Answer (score 3):

The gnome keyboard settings show the shortcut to move a window to another monitor is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + (<kbd>Left</kbd>, <kbd>Right</kbd>, <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd>).  If this doesn't work for you check in Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts(tab) > Navigation and see what the setting is for you.

Gnome versions < 3.18 (as far as I know) can get the same keyboard shortcuts using the [Put Windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/) extension from [extensions.gnome.org](http://extensions.gnome.org).  Settings for the extension can be changed using the gnome prefs tool (`gnome-shell-extension-prefs`)

Comment: That shortcut doesnt work. Navigation doesnt list to move windows to the next monitor.

Comment: I apologize. It does not look like gnome 3.10 supports this in the keyboard shortcuts but there is an extension you could try.   [Put Windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/
) might have what you are looking for.